# How to make GCC not to generate endbr64?

Tags: c, gcc

My gcc version is 9.3.0

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

According to gcc 9.3 manual

> -mmanual-endbr 
> Insert ENDBR instruction at function entry only via the cf_check function 
> attribute. This is useful when used with the option ‘-fcf-protection=branch’ 
> to control ENDBR insertion at the function entry.

From my understand, if I compile something using following command:

```
gcc -fcf-protection=branch -mmanual-endbr sth.c -o sth
```

The main function hasn't cf_check attribute, so there should isn't endbr64 at entry of main.

But it turns out still has endbr64 at entry.

So, how to make GCC not to generate endbr64?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing your own entry code?

Comment: yes, and the main just does some simple thing, just for test

Comment: You can specify your own entry with -nostartfiles and -e my_entry.